# Why System.Windows.FrameworkElement uses double type for properties like width and height?

Tags: c#, wpf

> Application.Current.MainWindow.Height

is a double type property defined in FrameworkElement . We could have used integer type as well,as screen resolutions are mostly integer types e.g, 480x600 . What can be the reason behind taking double type property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF units are not pixels.  The unit is 1/96th of an inch.  So a thickness of 1 is not necessarily 1 pixel.  It would only be 1 pixel if it was rendered to a display set to 96 dpi.  But a printer, or a screen that has a higher DPI, it might be multiple pixels.  Also, you can use fractional widths and it will anti-alias.

Take a look at the documentation for Thickness:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.thickness%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: In the link given by you there is a statement "px (default) is device-independent units (1/96th inch per unit)" . what exactly is a unit here and how it is defined?